# Piping stdout on windows to docker container running linux

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, docker, boot2docker, piping

I need to pipe the output of a program that only runs on Windows, to another program that only runs on Linux. (The programs are very similar to FFMPEG in functionality so for testing I'm piping FFMPEG stdout on Windows to FFMPEG stdin on Linux.)

I am using Docker to run a Linux container on Windows. Docker supports piping data from the host to the Docker container like this:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:a copy -v:a copy -f mpegts - | docker run ffmpeg-container -f mpegts -i - -c:a copy -c:v copy <output>
```

But Docker on Windows runs in a virtual machine and doesn't have a native client, which means I can't pipe directly to the container. So far I haven't been able to find any examples or discussions about piping data through the virtual machine on Windows.

I have tried alternative solutions like using `netcat` for piping but it has a much too slow throughput:

Windows:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:a copy -v:a copy -f mpegts - | ncat <ip address> <port>
```

Linux:

```
nc -l <ip address> <port> | ffmpeg -f mpegts -i - -c:a copy -c:v copy <output>
```

Transcoding purely in Windows yields about 100 FPS, while the netcat solution runs at 0.1 FPS. I am hoping that piping directly will give a better result.

Other solutions I've tried involve streaming the data from FFMPEG to FFMPEG using UDP - just to have the output come out of stdout, but the data was corrupted during the transfer. I suspect the problem was in the packets arriving out of order.

Any solutions similar to these will be greatly appreciated. The content is video data so solutions that uses FFMPEG to get the data across are acceptable.

Comment: `netcat` is not your limiting factor here, it is probably your disk or perhaps a bad network. Are you reading and writing to the same disk?

Comment: @Michael Yes, reading and writing is done on the same disk. It could be the network that is the limit, but doing a UDP stream from and to FFMPEG on the local machine runs much faster. The file ends up being corrupt when it arrives though.

Comment: I would test the throughput using netcat, I think you will find that when you spool to /dev/null it is much faster than when you write to disk.